# The Googlebot is only fetching my website's assets

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, fetch-as-google

When I try to use Fetch as Google on pages for my website, the Googlebot fetches it partially, and when I check the crawl log, tells me that some of my assets are temporarily unreachable:

[image: google not is not seeing my page well]

[image: some of my assets are not loaded , temporarily unreachable]

What should I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short Answer:*

Your hosting is in dire need of some TLC (tender loving care)

*Long Answer:*

Your website or hosting is extremely slow, so bad that a lot of users and bots will simply not wait for the page to render. A page should load within 5 seconds, ideally 1-2 seconds.

*Your site from EU:*
[image: Site Slow 1]

*Your site from US:*

The majority of search bots are hosted in the US, when testing your site, your site exceeded 60 seconds to load. Your website should be super responsive in your targetted region but it should also be crawlable in others, something that your is far off... Anything above 5+ seconds is not acceptable by Google's definition. Aim for 0.5-2 seconds for visitors, 1-3 seconds for SEO boost from Google and no more than 1-5 seconds for crawlers, slower sites, take longer to index pages and visitors are less likely to return.

> [John Muller from Google, answering a very similar question regarding 
>   Fetch as Google - Temporarily Unreachable](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/x-tAmtvK9iA/pDzGQsJMFKsJ)
>
> We're seeing an extremely high response-time for requests made to your
>   site (at times, over 2 seconds to fetch a single URL). This has
>   resulted in us severely limiting the number of URLs we'll crawl from
>   your site, and you're seeing that in Fetch as Google as well. My
>   recommendation would be to make sure that your server is fast &
>   responsive across the board. As our systems see a reduced
>   response-time, they'll automatically ramp crawling back up (which
>   gives you more room to use Fetch as Google too).